# System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. - Request.Url.Host

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The code line on where this is happening is on the response.redirect below:

```
Catch exR As System.NullReferenceException
    Dim dt As CustomDataObject = New CustomDataObject("SP_Retrieve_LoginPort")
    Dim port As Integer = dt.getdatatable.Rows(0).Item("Port")
    Response.Redirect("http://" & Request.Url.Host & ":" & port)
```

I get the following in my Request URL: http://©:53/Default.aspx

Where does the copyright symbol come from?

Comment: Could we see some more context, please?  What is the Try block doing that generates this exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult one, without more information.

I think that it may be to do with the string contents of `Request.Url.Host` and how it is displayed.

Char value &#169 and &copy will give you a copyright symbol.

I would, however, look at your host - do you have a web host setup e.g. IIS locally or are you relying on ASP.NET development server?

I would suggest that you setup a default web server and virtual directory for your project under IIS and then in dbug mode I'd expect `HttpRequest.Url.Host` to report back `localhost`